# Is there a way to store files in memory?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, virtual-machine

I have this problem with chrome: [Whenever g Google Chrome is open my HDD spins really fast](https://superuser.com/questions/370020/whenever-g-google-chrome-is-open-my-hdd-spins-really-fast/370025#370025)

Anyway, after reading [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19510), exerpt:

```
Hi Tim,

You can also tell Chrome to use a random folder for the profile data by adding a 
command line switch:

--user-data-dir=k:\whatever\path\I\want

That will place everything (cookies, history...) there.

Just for completeness, to move only the cache out of the profile directory:

--disk-cache-dir=c:\my_cache
```

I was thinking it would be great if i could just mount a chuck of memory as a hard disk and then direct chrome to use that. If this is possible then I'd imagine there should be some application out there can do it.

Does it sound possible? does anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible – see [RAM disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk).

On Windows NT, there exist several third-party drivers: [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk), Dataram [RAMDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk), and others. (Wikipedia has a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_disk_software).)

On Linux, use `mount -t tmpfs none /path` to mount a *tmpfs* instance on top of any directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the freeware [Gavotte RAMdisk](http://www.techsnack.net/gavotte-ramdisk-free-virtual-hardisk) for this under Windows XP.

If you are using a 32-bit operating system, you can use memory beyond the 3.25 GB limit for creating the RAM disk.  [Here is an article form Tom's Hardware about this.](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ram-memory-upgrade,2778-4.html)